# selenium not able to go to the page in FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Hi i'm using java10 with windows10 64bit and selenium 3.141.59.
while trying to invoke Firefox browser it gives me problem and chrome works fine.
code as follows

```
    public void test() {
        File gecko = new File("D:\\Soft\\geckodriver-v0.22.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");    
//  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", gecko.getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.geco.driver", gecko.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
        String expectedTitle = "Admin";
        String actualTitle = "";
        driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start. Build info:
>   version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'OPTIMIZEQ-LTP03', ip:
>   '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2' Driver info: driver.version:
>   FirefoxDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:247)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
>     at demo.selDemo.FireFoxDemo.test(FireFoxDemo.java:13)   at
>   demo.selDemo.App.main(App.java:14) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:18976/hub/status] to be available after 45002 ms
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:245)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>     ... 10 more

Comment: which version of gecko driver and firefox browser version are you using ?

Comment: geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64

Comment: firefox browser version ?

Comment: firexfox 65 selenium 3.14.xx java 10 winsows10 64bit

Comment: Thanks a liitle configuration issue was there now it has worked
try removing all the extensions from your browser and clear your history